# document.getElementById is null - automatic clicker

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-console

I have issues with using click function in chrome console.

I am using the following:

```js
document.getElementById('example').click();
```

and it works only if I inspect element, after that the element (example) is `null`.

I can reload it only by inspecting the element once again.

Is there any way to reload the element and make sure it is not null? Basically, I want it to be clicked automatically every 1 minute.

The code looks like this:

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="th-bt th-bt-text" onclick="thBtMgr.click(this);return htmlbSL(this,2,'example:Go','0')" onmousedown="thBtMgr.press(this,event);" onfocusout="thBtMgr.unpress(this);" onfocus="thSaveKbFocus(this);" oncontextmenu="return false;" ondragstart="return false;" id="example"> 
   <span class="th-bt-span">
      <b class="th-bt-b">Go</b>
   </span>
</a>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Just check to see if the element is `null` first, and only click if it isn't?

Comment: Why don't you just call the function that the anchor tag triggers when doing an `onclick`?

Comment: @putvande
I don't have an access to the code. I want to implement this automation for my personal use.

Comment: @CertainPerformance
Ok, but the element is null as long as I inspect it, and I want it to be automated.

Comment: When is the code running?

Comment: Yes, you can do this automatically - no need to inspect, just programatically check if it's `null` first. (`===` is strict equality comparison - use it)

Comment: if (example === undefined || example === null) {
}
else {
document.getElementById('example').click();
}

Do you mean something liek this? If so, it does not work :/ It says that variable is not defined.

Any ideas?